# ORA-06502/ORA-06512 errors using remote clob and dual

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

On Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production I'm trying get attributes names and values and compare them.

Here the request I've made (be gentle :D) :

```
SELECT ENV1.SKU,
ENV1.ATTRIBUTECODE ATTRIBUTECODE,
ENV1.ATTRIBUTEVALUE ATTRIBUTEVALUE_ENV1,
ENV2.ATTRIBUTEVALUE ATTRIBUTEVALUE_ENV2,
CASE
    WHEN ENV1.ATTRIBUTEVALUE IS NULL THEN 'ATTRIBUT MANQUANT SUR ENV1'
    WHEN ENV2.ATTRIBUTEVALUE IS NULL THEN 'ATTRIBUT MANQUANT SUR ENV2'
    WHEN ENV1.ATTRIBUTEVALUE != ENV2.ATTRIBUTEVALUE THEN 'MODIFICATION'
END DIFF
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT P.SKU, SUBSTR(X.ATTRIBUTENAME, 14, 3) ATTRIBUTECODE, X.ATTRIBUTEVALUE
                FROM PRODUCT P,
                XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr'
                    PASSING XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(P.ATTRIBUTES_FR_FR, '<attr name="longDescription">.*?<\/attr>'))
                    COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@name',
                            ATTRIBUTEVALUE VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '/string'
                ) X
                WHERE X.ATTRIBUTENAME LIKE 'Z_CA%'
                AND P.UUID IN (SELECT UUID FROM PRODUCT
                                WHERE DN(DOMAINID) = 'FR'
                                AND SKU NOT LIKE 'OFF_%' AND SKU NOT LIKE 'PDT%'
                                AND ATTRIBUTES_FR_FR IS NOT NULL)) ENV1
FULL JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT P.SKU, SUBSTR(X.ATTRIBUTENAME, 14, 3) ATTRIBUTECODE, X.ATTRIBUTEVALUE
            FROM PRODUCT@ENV2 P,
            XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr'
                PASSING XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(P.ATTRIBUTES_FR_FR, '<attr name="longDescription">.*?<\/attr>'))
                COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@name',
                        ATTRIBUTEVALUE VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '/string'
            ) X
            WHERE X.ATTRIBUTENAME LIKE 'Z_CA%'
            AND DN(DOMAINID) = 'FR'
            AND SKU NOT LIKE 'OFF_%' AND SKU NOT LIKE 'PDT%'
            AND (SELECT ATTRIBUTES_FR_FR FROM DUAL) IS NOT NULL) ENV2
ON ENV1.SKU = ENV2.SKU
AND ENV1.ATTRIBUTECODE = ENV2.ATTRIBUTECODE
WHERE (ENV1.ATTRIBUTEVALUE IS NULL OR ENV2.ATTRIBUTEVALUE IS NULL OR ENV1.ATTRIBUTEVALUE != ENV2.ATTRIBUTEVALUE)
ORDER BY ENV1.SKU ASC;
```

But there is an error :

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error string
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

When I try the ENV1 part on EV1 it's working, when try the ENV2 part without the dual on ENV2 it's working too, but when I try the ENV2 part on ENV1 using @ENV2 and the dual I have the same error, and I need to use the dual because if I don't use it have this error :

```
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
```

Using the dual changes something, but I don't know what. For some countries it's working, for some not so it's not everytime.

Can someone help a padawan ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a view on the remote node that performs the SQL operation on the LOB remotely.

Comment: Thank you so much Roger I haven't think about this solution.

Comment: @Dimitri I've used this solution in the past.  It gets around the issue because the operation is performed remotely.  Your SQL was a bit complex for me to unwind into example code, but you (knowing the requirements and design) should be able to work through the solution.  Have a nice day!!!